# how to create a user registration page and cheak if the user is already registered?

Tags: php, registration

I have designed a registration form where users are being registered by there name and phone no. now i want a script so that there should be a cheak before registering any user, that wheather the phone number is already been registered or not, only if the user is new he can register into and his data will be filled in the database...

Comment: You need to be more specific. How does your database look like and what have you tried to do so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope you could do this using this method

```
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
      $user_name= $_POST['name'];
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];

      $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$user_name' AND phone='$phone'");

     if( mysql_num_rows($check) ==0 ){
         //User is not exist run INSERT Query here
     }
     else
     {
        //User is Exist
        $exist = true;
        exit;
     }

}
```

Comment: I down voted this for recommending the use of the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: Can you explain the reason to down voted my answer?

Comment: I already did in my previous comment.

Comment: @sameerali, don't take it personally. He downvoted mine as well. And the funny thing is that I don't see an answer from him. Hilarious.

Comment: @Lalien-MilesLamarColeman I have provided over 400 answers on this site, but this question shows no effort and I don't think it deserves an answer. However, answers that are given should be accurate and promote best practice. Those I've down voted here don't and I've pointed out which part of the answers I have concerns with.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to query the database table holding info about the already registered users and see if that is already there:

eg:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE phone = '123456'")) {

    if($result->num_rows == 0)
        //register user
    else
        // send error message
}
```

Comment: Please see mysqli_ or PDO as mysql_ functions are depricated. It's bad that most tutorials for beginners feature mysql_ functions, making it hard to get rid of this bad habit. We try to do the same here, so a small edit will do the future generation good. :)

Comment: thanks for the help, now i need to ask i more thing.   suppose i want to generate passwords for the users and send that password to there phone number.. can you help me

Comment: I wrote it that way as not everyone knows what OOP PHP is so mysql_ functions would have been eaier to understand. I have edited it so I am on the same wave length with the others who want to help

Comment: I down voted this for not using parameters in the query.

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to do all of your work for you, but I'll gladly point you in the right direction.

You can do a SELECT query on your users table with the desired username in the WHERE clause and you can use the `mysql_num_rows($queryCallback)` function in an if statement to see if there are one or more rows returned. If there are, then the process will be terminated and you can just send the user back with an error message.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = "monkeyballs";
```

*Returns 1 Row*

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
   return false; 
   //terminate the registration
} else {
  //INSERT query and whatnot
}
```

Good luck!

I recommend you research MySQL functions in PHP or pick up a framework. CakePHP makes registration / logging in a breeze. Just my two cents for you.

Comment: I down voted this for recommending the use of the deprecated mysql_* functions.